Laravel: Function return "Object" instead of "Array"
I'm building a diet plan with Laravel 8.
Database looks like this:



Recipes
Category
Calories




Eggs
breakfast
180


Yogourt
breakfast
50


Apple pie
snacks
289


Banana pie
snacks
386


Tomato Pasta
lunch-dinner
712


Chicken Salad
lunch-dinner
956


Vegetables soup
lunch-dinner
410


Fish with potatoes
lunch-dinner
652



I'd like to get the day's meals according to average daily calories.
For example, if my daily calories is 1500kcal, I want to get 4 recipes (breakfast/lunch/dinner/snacks) for the day whose total calories are between 1300-1500 calories.
I use the same category for lunch and dinner but I need 2 results from this category.
I built some functions to do this:
use App\Models\Recipe;

// Function to generate combinations of recipes
function generateCombinations($items, $n, $start = 0, $result = [], &$results = []) {
    if ($n === 0) {
        $results[] = $result;
        return;
    }

    for ($i = $start; $i < count($items); $i++) {
        $result[] = $items[$i];
        generateCombinations($items, $n - 1, $i + 1, $result, $results);
        array_pop($result);
    }
}

// Function to filter combinations by total calories
function filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCaloriesMin, $dailyCalories) {
    return array_filter($combinations, function($combination) use ($dailyCaloriesMin, $dailyCalories) {
        $totalCalories = array_sum(array_column($combination, 'calories'));
        return $totalCalories >= $dailyCaloriesMin && $totalCalories <= $dailyCalories;
    });
}

// Function to get daily meal plan
function getDailyMealPlan($dailyCalories, $dailyCaloriesMin) {
    $mealCategories = ['breakfast', 'lunch-dinner', 'snacks'];
    $mealPlan = [];

    foreach ($mealCategories as $category) {
        $recipes = Recipe::where('meal', $category)->get()->toArray();

        // Generate combinations of recipes for this meal category
        $combinations = [];
        if ($category == 'lunch-dinner') {
            generateCombinations($recipes, 2, 0, [], $combinations);
        } else {
            generateCombinations($recipes, 1, 0, [], $combinations);
        }

        // Filter combinations by total calories
        $filteredCombinations = filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCaloriesMin, $dailyCalories);

        // If there are no valid combinations, choose a single recipe with the highest calories
        if (empty($filteredCombinations)) {
            $selectedRecipe = Recipe::where('meal', $category)->orderBy('calories', 'desc')->first();
            $mealPlan[$category] = $selectedRecipe;
        } else {
            // Randomly select a combination from the filtered combinations
            $selectedCombination = $filteredCombinations[array_rand($filteredCombinations)];
            $mealPlan[$category] = $selectedCombination;
        }
    }

    return $mealPlan;
}

But when I do:
$mealPlan = getDailyMealPlan($dailyCalories, $dailyCaloriesMin);
dd($mealPlan);

I get an Object for breakfast, an Object for snacks and one Array with 2 results for lunch-dinner
See here:
array:3 [▼
  "breakfast" => App\Models\Recipe {#1388 ▶}
  "lunch-dinner" => array:2 [▶]
  "snacks" => App\Models\Recipe {#1736 ▶}
]

I don't understand why I don't get 3 Array. I would like to obtain this result:
array:3 [▼
  "breakfast" => array:1 [▶]
  "lunch-dinner" => array:2 [▶]
  "snacks" => array:1 [▶]
]

Any solution?

First off, this will be very hard to maintain in the long run. For your expected results, you are returning a single Model object when writing Recipe::where(..)->first(). So convert the object to an array with toArray(). Keep in mind you have to set your model attributes straight when converting to an array. If you just want the object to be returned in a single result collection (for consistency reasons) don't use ->first() but return the collection when using Recipe::where(..)->get().
